# Passing variables between *.pro files

Tags: qt, global-variables, qmake

I have the following *.pro files :

the one which heads the solution

```
# head - pro file :
TEMPLATE = subdirs
CONFIG = qt thread ordered

# save root directory
PROJECT_ROOT_DIRECTORY = $$_PRO_FILE_PWD_
message("Master pro file path : ["$${PROJECT_ROOT_DIRECTORY}"]") // output : "Master pro file path : [/Path/To/Directory]"

# project subdirs
SUBDIRS += PROJECT1
```

and

```
# PROJECT1 - pro file :
TEMPLATE = app

# etc.

# output 'PROJECT_ROOT_DIRECTORY ' contents
message("Master pro file path : "$${PROJECT_ROOT_DIRECTORY}) // output :  "Master pro file path : []"
```

How do I pass variables between the 2 pro files (here the variable is `PROJECT_ROOT_DIRECTORY`) ?

**Edit :**

This is the same question as this [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450630/variables-that-persist-across-pro-files-from-a-subdirs-pro-file?rq=1), but I don't see how the "*another option is to*" answer can help me.

Comment: You re-post, then? And if you didnt get the right answer, why did you set it as accepted anyway?

Comment: @PatrickBassut Yes you are right, it's not very consistent. But still, if a better answer appears I'll move the acceptance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could put the variable definitions in a `.pri` file, which you then include in all `.pro` files you want. Note that you need to tell the `.pro` files in your subdirectories the path where to find the `.pri` file.

**head.pro:**

```
# head - pro file :
TEMPLATE = subdirs
CONFIG = qt thread ordered

# configuration
include(config.pri)
message("Master pro file path : ["$${PROJECT_ROOT_DIRECTORY}"]") # output : "Master pro file path : [/Path/To/Directory]"

# project subdirs
SUBDIRS += PROJECT1
```

**config.pri:**

```
# save root directory
PROJECT_ROOT_DIRECTORY = $$PWD // not $$_PRO_FILE_PWD_!
```

**project1/project1.pro:**

```
# PROJECT1 - pro file :
TEMPLATE = app

# configuration
include(../config.pri)  # note that you need to put "../" before the .pri path
message("Master pro file path : ["$${PROJECT_ROOT_DIRECTORY}"]") # should now output :  "Master pro file path : [/Path/To/Directory]"
```

Comment: ok, sounds good to me. So this is always a matter of workaround, you can't pass variables by value between `*.pro` files ?

Comment: At least I don't know a way to do so. Maybe there is a better workaround. If someone else posts a better solution, don't hesitate to move the acceptance...

Comment: https://wiki.qt.io/QMake-top-level-srcdir-and-builddir this might be a solution which define variable in .qmake.conf after qt-5.