# How to check if qmake project is under 'subdirs' template?

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qmake, subdirectory

I have a project file that is a part of a 'subdirs' TEMPLATE (but can as well be used standalone).

I tried testing the TEMPLATE variable but the following snippet prints NO when executed as a part of a bigger project.

```
equals(TEMPLATE, subdirs) {
   message(YES)
} else {
   message(NO)
}
```

How do I check if this project file is processed as a part of bigger project or independently?

Answer (score 0):

The variable TEMPLATE is reset in each sub-project which explains why the snippet above print "NO". Although not elegant, my current workaround for this problem is to define a STANDALONE flag in `.qmake.cache` as described in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450630/variables-that-persist-across-pro-files-from-a-subdirs-pro-file).