# QMake - pass variable to child projects

Tags: qt, qmake

I have a qmake project with these project files:

```
. parent1.pro
. parent2.pro  
. child_common.pro
```

parent1 and parent2 are both subdirs project and have child_common as a subdir.

Is there a way for me to define a variable usable by child_common that have a different value based on which parent the child is used by?

For instance: if I'm compiling parent1, child_common should have a variable MY_VAR=A. If I'm compiling parent2 it should have MY_VAR=B

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, in fact it's not how the things are supposed to be done (as `qmake` never allows to pass its variables onto the `SUBDIRS` subprojects), so you may eventually end up having two separate `child_common` instances. However, if all your projects belong to the same directory subtree, you can make use of the qmake's cache file in the following way.

First, create an empty cache file in your common root subdirectory: `touch .qmake.cache` (or `.qmake.stash`, or `.qmake.super`). Then add the following to all your "parent" projects:

```
MY_VAR = A # or B
cache(MY_VAR, set) # or "set stash", or "set super"
```

Now `MY_VAR` should be visible inside any of your subprojects, as long as the cache file exists in the parent directory. But notice that the changes of the cache contents do not automatically imply the (sub)project rebuild.

Comment: I use QtCreator version 4.9 and your trick works for me regardless if there is a cache file present or not. I wonder what triggers the creation of those files and what determines their suffix though.

Comment: @PatrickFromberg touch is needed to ensure that the cache file is created in a common parent directory, and not in the current (sub-)project's $$PWD. Normally, a cache file is created when first time writing to it, of course. The suffixes are predefined and come from the second parameter of `cache()` call - set cash/stash/super. There could be all three caches at the sime time, as they have different priorities. For further details, you may refer to qmake source code (qmakebuiltins.cpp).